# SQL query for finding records where count > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have 2 tables ACCOUNT and ACC_TRANSACTION

Account have PK

ACC_TRANSACTION have

```
ACC_TRANSACTION_ACCOUNT_FK 
    foreign key (ACCOUNT_ID) 
    references ACCOUNT;
```

I need to SELECT all ACCOUNT where i need COUNT all ACC_TRANSACTION (for every account)

Like if

1. ACC_TRANSACTION.ACCOUNT_ID = 1;
2. ACC_TRANSACTION.ACCOUNT_ID = 1

then 1)ACCOUNT have 2 transactions

Comment: Do you simply want `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to bring the number of transactions of each account. One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*, 
    (select count(*) from acc_transactions t where t.account_id = a.account_id) cnt_transactions
from accounts a
```

Comment: Yes it is, ty. But what is cnt_transactions?

Comment: @Usagi: that's just an alias for the column that holds the count of transations.